# Get the compressed response length in ASP.net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, middleware, kestrel-http-server

I've build a RESTful API using .net Core running on Kestrel. I've just enabled compression using "GzipCompressionProvider" middleware as described [here](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/17281/Using-response-compression-in-ASPNET-Core-11/27848#.Wyi9yp8zaUk).

I'm also using a custom logger that logs all requests/responses to a DB with the response and request lengths as per below:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
    provider.Mappings[".apk"] = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    app.UseMiddleware<myMiddleware.LoggerMiddleware>();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });            
}
```

The implementation of the Logger middleware is as follows:

```
public LoggerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, AuditContext dbcontext, IOptions<AppSettings> appsettings, IConfiguration config, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
{
    _next = next;
    dbContext = dbcontext;
    appSettings = appsettings;
    _config = config;
    loggerFactory = loggerfactory;
}

public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    ApiLogEntry apiLog = null;
    using (MemoryStream requestBodyStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (MemoryStream responseBodyStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Stream originalRequestBody = context.Request.Body;
            context.Request.EnableRewind();
            Stream originalResponseBody = context.Response.Body;

            try
            {
                await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestBodyStream);
                requestBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                string requestBodyText = new StreamReader(requestBodyStream).ReadToEnd();

                requestBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                context.Request.Body = requestBodyStream;

                string responseBody = "";

                context.Response.Body = responseBodyStream;

                Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                await _next(context);
                watch.Stop();

                responseBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                responseBody = new StreamReader(responseBodyStream).ReadToEnd();
                string appName = "Tracy";
                if (context.Request.Headers["tracy-app"] != "")
                {
                    appName = context.Request.Headers["tracy-app"];
                }
                string token = "";
                var authorization = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

                if (authorization == "" || !authorization.Contains("Bearer"))
                {
                } else
                {
                    token = authorization.Remove(0, 7).Trim();
                }
                string requestHeaders = string.Join(",", context.Request.Headers.Select(he => he.Key + ":[" + he.Value + "]").ToList());
                string responseHeaders = string.Join(",", context.Response.Headers.Select(he => he.Key + ":[" + he.Value + "]").ToList());

                apiLog = new ApiLogEntry
                {
                    Application = appName,
                    Machine = Environment.MachineName,
                    RequestContentType = context.Request.ContentType,
                    RequestRouteTemplate = context.Request.Path,
                    RequestRouteData = requestBodyText,
                    RequestIpAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString(),
                    RequestMethod = context.Request.Method,
                    RequestHeaders = requestHeaders,
                    RequestTimestamp = DateTime.Now,
                    RequestUri = (context.Request.IsHttps ? "https://" : "http://") + context.Request.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value + context.Request.Path,
                    ResponseContentType = context.Response.ContentType,
                    ResponseHeaders = responseHeaders,
                    ResponseStatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
                    RequestLength = requestBodyText.Length + requestHeaders.Length,
                    ResponseLength = responseBody.Length + responseHeaders.Length,
                    Duration = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                    SimId = context.Request.Headers["sim-serialnumber"],
                    DeviceId = context.Request.Headers["tracy-deviceid"],
                    ClientAppVersion = context.Request.Headers["app-version"],
                    UserId = dws.tracy.Security.AuthHelpers.GetUserId(appSettings, token)
                };

                if (appSettings.Value.Logging.LogResponse)
                {
                    apiLog.ResponseContentBody = responseBody;
                }
                responseBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                await responseBodyStream.CopyToAsync(originalResponseBody);
                if (apiLog != null && appSettings.Value.Logging.IsActive)
                {
                    var apilogDB = Mapper.Map<dws.Data.ApiLogEntry>(apiLog);
                    using (var logContext = new AuditContext(_config.GetConnectionString("DwsContext")))
                    {
                        var apiLogRepo = new dws.Data.Repositories.ApiLogEntryRepository(logContext);
                        apiLogRepo.Add(apilogDB);
                        apiLogRepo.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ExceptionLogger.LogToDatabse(ex);
                string innerException = "";
                if (ex.InnerException!=null)
                {
                    innerException = ex.InnerException.Message;
                }

                ILogger logger;
                logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("LoggerEntry");
                logger.LogCritical(ex.ToString());
                logger.LogCritical(innerException);

                byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Server error");
                context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                originalResponseBody.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            }
            finally
            {
                context.Request.Body = originalRequestBody;
                context.Response.Body = originalResponseBody;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trouble is that the ResponseLength is always the pre-compression length. Any suggestions on what I need to change. I'm assuming the issue is that the response is being compressed only when it is flushed to the client? Am I able to add my logger after that point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
app.UseResponseCompression();
app.UseMiddleware<myMiddleware.LoggerMiddleware>();
```

With that order, the response compression middleware will be placed *in front of* your middleware. That means compression middleware will get request before your middleware, but process response *after* your middleware.

Try to add your middleware before `UseResponseCompression()` and you should see compressed content.

Reference: [ASP.NET Core Middleware Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#creating-a-middleware-pipeline-with-iapplicationbuilder)